# How to get something like `MyClass<String>.class` in java

Tags: java, class, reflection, ninjaframework

I am trying to create a custom [`ArgumentExtractor` in Ninjaframework](http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/basic_concepts/argument_extractors.html), in which I have to create a class that implements `ninja.params.ArgumentExtractor<T>` which has method `public Class<T> getExtractedType()`

```
import java.util.Optional;
class OptionalParamExtractor implements ArgumentExtractor<Optional<String>> {
    ...
    @Override
    public Class<Optional<String>> getExtractedType() {
        return Optional<String>.class; // Compiler don't let me do this.
    }
}
```

At the line `return Optional<String>.class;`, I got a syntax error. How can I properly return the object of type `Class<Optional<String>>` in this case? I tried

```
    @Override
    public Class<Optional<String>> getExtractedType() {
        return Optional.of("").getClass();
    }
```

But did not work, I got an error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#1-of ? extends Optional> to Class<Optional<String>>`

Comment: Can you just cast it and suppress the warning? `return (Class<Optional<String>>) Optional.of("").getClass();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return Optional.class. The type argument `<String>` won't survive erasure anyway. You can never get that part at runtime.